# Show $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert^2}$ is orientation reversing.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orientation

I wanted to show that the map $\mathbb{R}^n- \{0\} → \mathbb{R}^n- \{0\},\ x\mapsto \frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert^2}$ is orientation reversing. But i don't know how to tackle it appropriately.

The solution proposed the following:

> At $p = (1,0,...,0)$ the differential of the given map is the identity
> on $0 \oplus \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \subset T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ while it is
> multiplication by $-1$ on $\mathbb{R}  \oplus 0 \subset
>  T_p\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Then they justify it by connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $n$ greater than $1$.

I am not sure whether I fully understand the solution. For simplicity let's assume $n = 2$, then at $(1,0)$ the differential of the map is $(-1,1)$, similarly $(-1,1,1...,1)$ for arbitrary $n$. How is it the identity on $0 \oplus \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \subset T_p\mathbb{R}^n$?

Could someone elaborate? I tried to look up similar problems in my books but couldn't find any. I would really like to understand this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you're right. In any case, to show that it's orientation reversing, you just need to show that the determinant of the Jacobian is always negative. To do this, it suffices to show that the Jacobian is always invertible and, since the space is connected, show that it has negative determinant at one point, where the determinant is particularly easy to calculate., like $(1,0,\cdots, 0)$.

Comment: It should be "...multiplication by $-1$ on $\mathbb{R} \oplus 0$, no?

Comment: @cavok yes, indeed. that was a typo on my side. fixing it immediately.

Comment: @Deane usually, we need to compute the jacobian for all transition maps. In this case it suffices to just compute one since we don't need any transition maps between charts since we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, am i correct? Why does connectedness imply that an invertible Jacobian means the determinant is negative? Couldn't it be positive either?

Comment: Although this question arises in a discussion about coordinate charts, your question does not require that. A map is orientation reversing if and only if its Jacobian has negative determinant everywhere. If the determinant is everywhere nonzero on a connected domain, then either it is always positive or it is always negative. So to figure out which one it is, it suffices to check the sign at a single point in the domain.

Comment: I should point out something else. Showing directly that the Jacobian is invertible might not be so easy. An easier indirect method is to show that the map has an (obvious) inverse map, which is also smooth. This implies that the Jacobian is everywhere invertible.

Comment: Thanks Deane, that's quite helpful. Also, the given answers help providing a better intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the matrix representing the differential in standard coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, the Jacobian of the given map: The derivative of the $j$-th component of $\frac{x}{ \| x \|^2}$ with respect to $x^i$, is $\frac{ \delta_i^j \| x \|^2 - 2 x_i x^j }{ \| x \|^4}$.  Evaluated at the point $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$, this gives zero if $i \ne j$, gives $-1$ if $i=j=1$, and $1$ if $i = j \ne 1$, so the Jacobian is block diagonal with the upper left $1\times 1$ block being $-1$ and the lower right $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ block being the identity, which is what the solution you quote is saying in a nicer way.

Makes sense geometrically too, as the map is an inversion in the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and at any point $p$, any tangent vectors perpendicular to $p$ are simply rescaled by $1/\|p\|^2$, whereas the ones parallel to $p$ switch direction.

Comment: Thanks cavok, this was quite helpful indeed. Highly appreciating your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\vec{f}(x)=\frac{\vec{x}}{x\cdot x}$, which coordinate-wise is
$$
f_j(x)=\frac{x_j}{x\cdot x}\tag1
$$
The Jacobian of $f$ is
$$
\partial_if_j(x)=\frac{\delta_{ij}x\cdot x-2x_ix_j}{(x\cdot x)^2}\tag2
$$
Written as matrices, this is
$$
\frac{I-2\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx}}{x^Tx}\tag3
$$
The matrix $I-2\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx}$ is a reflection in the direction of $x$; that is, locally, the map flips in the radial direction and scales by the inverse of the square of the distance from the origin.

The reflection reverses the orientation.